# On linux, how to get "incompatible" i386 f77 libraries to work with current Fortran compilers, like gfortran?

Tags: c++, linux

I would like to run the elf32-i386 library [libkernlib.a](http://cernlib.web.cern.ch/cernlib/download/2006b_i686-slc5-gcc34-opt/lib/) with a Fortran 77 program on my latest Ubuntu linux machine. From what I've read, `gfortran` is backwards compatible with Fortran 77, but I'm having trouble to get it to work with the library.  I've tried -ff2c, -fbackflash, etc. but everything is still giving me

```
$ gfortran -ff2c -O -o output f77fortran.f -lkernlib

/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/local/lib/libkernlib.a when searching for -lkernlib
/usr/bin/ld: canot find -lkernlib
```

I have also tried using `fort77`. I cannot find a `f77` that works. **If anyone knows how to run f77 programs and its libraries, whether using `gfortran` or something else, that would be great.**

Btw, the libkernlib.a library has older versions from "libraries" links on [this page](http://cernlib.web.cern.ch/cernlib/version.html), but the ones I've tried all give the same error and are all i386 (I figured out that by `objdump -f libkernlib.a`).

Context: This is part of a Mathematica [project](http://mbtools.hepforge.org/) that uses old code.

Comment: Adding `-m32` works, so $ gfortran -m32 -O -o output f77fortran.f -lkernlib

Comment: Good! Can you write a short answer yourself, so the question does not stay open?

Answer (score 2):

Actually `-m32` works better than `-ff2c` for me, I didn't have to use `-ff2c` at all.

```
$ gfortran -m32 -O -o output f77fortran.f -lkernlib
```

Then I got some other errors with 32 bit or f77 compatibility that were solved with adding the packages:

- lib32gfortran-4.8-dev
- gcc-multilib